# Jekyll loop pages by parent directory

Tags: jekyll

My Jekyll site is comprised of pages in folders. Like this:

```
modules
- week 1
-- topic 1
-- topic 2
-- topic 3
- week 2
-- topic 1
- week 3
-- topic 1
```

Here's a screenshot of my Sublime folder view: http://glui.me/?i=884mtx2vcyv7fjx/2014-08-26_at_11.26_AM.png/

I can just do a simple `{% for page in site.pages %}` to output a flat list of all the pages in the site, but I want to maintain that folder structure.

Any ideas for how I might output a list that mirrors the directory structure I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This pages scheme

```
--modules
    |
    --schedule
    |  |--schedule-01.html
    |  |--schedule-02.html
    | 
    --week01
    |  |--topic-01.html
    |  |--topic-02.html
    |  |--topic-11.html
    |  
    --week02
    |  |--topic-01.html
    |  |--topic-02.html
    |
    --week11
    |  |--topic-01.html
    |  |--topic-02.html 
    |
    |...
```

can be nicely sorted and presented in a menu

Example page modules/week01/topic-01.html

```
---
title: Week 1 - Topic 01
layout: page or any custome module layout
menu: modules
---

Topic 01 content
```

And finally the modules.html page with his menu

```
<h2>Modules list</h2>

{% assign sorted = site.pages | sort: "url" %}
<ul>
{% for p in sorted %}
{% if p.menu == "modules" %}
  <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```